# How to make an inside div with text to be responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a parent div with a responsive background image. Inside the parent div I have a child div with some text in it. I want the text inside the child div, and the child div itself, to be responsive too.

Don't want to do that with the `table` attribute.
Is there any other solution?

[here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/bill123/xb548oqt/)

Comment: Define what you mean by responsive.

Comment: ^^^ do you mean interactive somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/xb548oqt/2/

use `<img>` instead of `background-image`

```css
.parent {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.parent img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  padding: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 1.2em;
  font-size: .5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img src="http://i42.photobucket.com/albums/e340/BillysGtr_Nakos/m_zps8802bbe3.jpg" />
  <div class="child">
    <h2>some text</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Strictly speaking `img` is considered content, `background-image` is considered styling. In this case the image is clearly a background and thus styling...

Comment: i have `img` so that the parent `div` takes the `height` of the image

Comment: that was exactly what i was looking for! Thanks a lot. But can you explain why background-image don't work on that?

Comment: I see why you did it, I'm just saying that strictly speaking it is not correct and should be done another way... I also know we don't live in an ideal world and I probably have sinned against this myself.

Comment: @PeterVR, you are right. The above code can stand alone but there are some problems when I tested in a project with other elements. What is your suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure, what your issue is, but as long as you don't use anything like `white-space: nowrap;` a DIV with some text should be responsive by default. Just set the DIV to `width: 100%;` (which is the default) and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by responsive here, but looking at your example I think you may be looking for `background-size: cover;`. Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/xb548oqt/1/